# How to color objects based on external CSV data?

Tags: python, materials, objects

Is it possible to color vertices according to a temperature data in Blender with Python script?

Let's say I have 10 coordinates xyz, which have their own temperature value.

1 is 3°C, 2 is -4, 3 is 0, 4 is +5, 6 is -8, 7 is +10, 8 is +3, 9 is -2, 10   is +1

So the coldest is -8 will be green, the warmest is +10 will be red. How to color all of them automatically?

In my project I have 130.000 coordinates (astronomical data in csv-file). I can build them. But how to color now?

Also I have density value for each coordinate. But it's not possible to change a vertex size, right? Is it any way to "switch on" density also?

Image is just to illustrate, how it should like in Blender.
[image: example illustration]

Comment: Can you share a dataset for testing a solution?